# using TCL trace on a local variable of a proc

Tags: variables, tcl, trace, proc

Say I have this TCL code (this is a simplistic example):

```
proc foo {} {
   set k {0}
   foreach a { 1 2 3 4 } {
      lappend k [ expr { [lindex $k end ] + $a } ]
   }
}
```

I want to trace the k variable within proc foo, just as I would trace it, had it been a global or a namespace variable. How can I do that, in TCL 8.5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even local variables can also be traced. It does not need to be a static/global or namespace variable.

```
proc trackMyVar {name element op} {
    # In case of array variable tracing, the 'element' variable will specify the array index
    # For scalar variables, it will be empty
    if {$element != ""} {
        set name ${name}($element)
    }
    upvar $name x
    if {$op eq "r"} {
        puts "Variable $name is read now. It's value : $x"
    } elseif {$op eq "w"} {
        puts "Variable $name is written now. New value : $x"
    } elseif {$op eq "u"} {
        puts "Variable $name is unset"
    } else {
        # Only remaining possible value is "a" which is for array variables 
        # For array variables, tracing will work only if they have accessed/modified with array commands
    }
}


proc foo {} {
    # Adding tracing for variable 'k'
    trace variable k rwu trackMyVar
    set k {0}
    foreach a { 1 2 3 4 } {
        lappend k [ expr { [lindex $k end ] + $a } ]
    }
    unset k; # Just added this to demonstrate 'unset' operation
}
```

**Output**

```
% foo
Variable k is written now. New value : 0
Variable k is read now. Its's value : 0
Variable k is written now. New value : 0 1
Variable k is read now. Its's value : 0 1
Variable k is written now. New value : 0 1 3
Variable k is read now. Its's value : 0 1 3
Variable k is written now. New value : 0 1 3 6
Variable k is read now. Its's value : 0 1 3 6
Variable k is written now. New value : 0 1 3 6 10
Variable k is unset
%
```

The command syntax of `trace` is as follows

> trace variable name ops command

Here, 'ops' indicates which operations are of interest, and is a list of one or more of the following items

- array
- read
- write
- unset

which should be specified as with their first letters as `arwu`. You can use whichever you are interested to track. I have used `rwu`. If you want to track only read operation then use `r` alone in it.

Reference : [trace](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm)

Comment: Hello Dinesh. Thanks. This would mean that I need to change the code itself of the function, unlike the global or namespace variables, which can be traced w/o changing the code in which they reside.
Is that correct?
Thanks.

Comment: `trace` will applicable as long as you retain the scope in which it is accessible.

Comment: You can also trace the proc, and inject your trace with uplevel. Have fun building a debugger :P